# Как выделить «-ть» в неопределённой форме глагола?

Tags: глаголы, окончания, морфемный-разбор, суффиксы, преподавание

В учебнике для классов с нерусским языком обучения ("Русская речь", 5 класс) **-ть** даётся как окончание неопределённой формы глагола, хотя во всех учебных пособиях по институтской программе, да и просто по логике (окончание — изменяемая часть слова, которая служит для образования формы слова и связи слов в словосочетании), это суффикс НФГ.
Так как же давать эту часть слова детям? Я объясняю, что **-ть** — это суффикс и что в учебнике опечатка. Правильно ли я поступаю?

Answer (score 3):

Да наверное, правильно.
Просто это очень давняя история, раньше, очень давно, "-ть" считали окончанием, теперь методика (или что уж там) поменялась.
Ну как детям объяснить, что взрослые дяди договориться не могут?!

Comment: ***behemothus: "очень давно, "-ть" считали окончанием, теперь методика (или что уж там) поменялась."***
В учебниках под ред. Львова снова -ть считается окончанием. В других - суффиксом, но формообразующим.

Comment: Я имел в виду те времена, когда школьные учебники были едины - и не противоречили (в основных хотя бы вещах) "официальной" академической грамматике.

Answer (score 2):

Да, некоторые учёные рассматривают **-ть** как суффикс, а некоторые (Бабайцева) — как окончание. Единого решения по этому вопросу нет.
Но если все сходятся во мнении, что инфинитив — это неизменяемая форма, то логичнее считать **-ть** суффиксом, ведь словосочетания типа *мечтал купить* мы относим к примыканию, а примыкать могут только неизменяемые слова.

Answer (score 0):

Если инфинитив не изменяется, то -ТЬ, естественно, суффикс. Но я знаю, что некоторые учителя предлагают из этой морфемы делать "домик": выделять окончание и суффикс одновременно.

Answer (score 0):

Инфинитив - исходная форма (форма!) глагола, от него образуются формы всех времен. Так что утверждать, что инфинитив не изменяется, неверно, по-моему. Поэтому  -ть можно выделять либо как окончание, либо как суффикс, но формообразующий. В этом я согласна с  Ларf.

Answer (score 0):

Однако если считать ОКОНЧАНИЕ неопределённой ФОРМЫ глагола суффиксом, то почему бы не считать суффиксом ОКОНЧАНИЕ глагола в ФОРМЕ прошедшего времени третьего лица женского рода?

Вполне себе приличный суффикс "ала" получается...

Comment: Разница между суффиксом и окончанием в том, что второе служит исключительно для связи слов в предложении, а в первый, даже в формообразующий, заложена смысловая составляющая. О суффиксах неопределенного времени можно спорить, раньше их и считали окончанием особого рода, но никак не о родовом окончании, которое меняется при склонении - и только.

Answer (score -1):

Ть - это окончание! И никаких вопросов! В русском языке всего две части речи, не имеющие окончания, т.е. заканчивающиеся суффиксом - это наречие и деепричастие! У нас начальная школа докатилась уже до того, что при разборе выдают следующую картину:

> Писать - корень (пис), суфф (а), суфф (ть), нулевое окончание.

Вообще ни в какие рамки. Что хочу, то и ворочу.

Comment: Когда-то, во времена единой линии учебников, -ть считали окончанием. Сейчас единого мнения нет. В одних учебниках (Разумовской, например)это уже суффикс, в других (Ладыженской, Бабайцевой) по-прежнему окончание. В пользу окончания действует тот аргумент, то НФ  - это  форма, которая  меняет конец слова в парадигме глагола.Но на суффикс -ть (-ти) все-таки больше похоже: эта морфема не входит ни в одну парадигму окончаний, как и положено этой морфеме;в словосочетании связь  примыкание, при котором зависимым может быть только неизменяемое слово. В неизменяемом нет окончания.

Comment: Это формообразующий суффикс, который не  входит в основу слова.